# Read and insert data from .txt file to Oracle SQL DB [PL/SQL, Unix Scripting]

Tags: sql, bash, unix, plsql, scripting

i have an input file: `$home/dir/subdir/input.txt`

content of input.txt:

```
123,0000,11111,3,1,X
124,0001,11112,3,1,Y
125,0002,,4,2,Y
129,0003,11114,4,2,X
```

I have a table where col2, col3 cannot be null:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 | col9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 123 | 0000 | 11111 |  |  | 3 | 1 | X |
|  | 124 | 0001 | 11112 |  |  | 3 | 1 | Y |
|  | 129 | 0003 | 11114 |  |  | 4 | 2 | X |

How do I insert the contents of `input.txt` to the table accordingly? using pl/sql and unix scripting

Comment: It seems col1 is null, in fact.

Comment: you can use an external table for that. Plenty of examples on google. No unix scripting needed.

Comment: hi @choroba, col1 and other cols are null. which means that the data from .txt are assigned to specific columns.

Comment: So why "col1, col2, col3 cannot be null"?

Comment: it's just col2, and col3. i have updated it. 3rd row from input.txt should not be inserted

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `regexp_substr` function.

In the following example, I used the `regexp_like` function to confirm it was in the given format. Adjust it as you like.
Example:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(string, '[^,]+', 1, 1) as col2,
       regexp_substr(string, '[^,]+', 1, 2) as col3, 
       regexp_substr(string, '[^,]+', 1, 3) as col4, 
       regexp_substr(string, '[^,]+', 1, 4) as col7,
       regexp_substr(string, '[^,]+', 1, 5) as col8,
       regexp_substr(string, '[^,]+', 1, 6) as col9,  
FROM   table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(string, '[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[A-Za-z]+');
```

Result:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| - | 123 | 0000 | 11111 | - | - | 3 | 1 | X |
| - | 129 | 0003 | 11114 | - | - | 4 | 2 | X |
| - | 124 | 0001 | 11112 | - | - | 3 | 1 | Y |